# Passing two bundles to two different activities

Tags: android, bundle

I have an Activty `Voice` that shoots 2 different bundles off to two different activities.

```
    Bundle a = new Bundle();
    a.putInt("key", counter_score);
    Intent sendtoA = new Intent(Voice.this, ActivityA.class);
    sendtoA.putExtras(a);
    startActivity(sendtoA);

    String correct_a = txView.getText().toString();
    Bundle basket_a = new Bundle();
    basket_a.putString("keya", correct_a);
    Intent putBasket_a = new Intent(Voice.this, ActivityFinal.class);
    putBasket_a.putExtras(basket_a);


 finish();
```

I catch Bundle `a`  fine on both `ActivityA` and on `ActivityFinal` with

```
Bundle got_a = getIntent().getExtras();
gota = got_a.getInt("key");
```

However I cant retrieve basket_a

```
Bundle gotA = getIntent().getExtras();
gotLetterA = gotA.getString("keya");
txView.setText("Nice" + gotLetterA);
```

One bundle is passing and int the other is passing a string.

For gotA on ActivityFinal, the result shows null..

thnx

Comment: You aren't calling a `startActivity` for `basket_a`. Why?

Comment: I was under the impression that calling `startActivity` for `basket_a`  with `startActivity(sendtoA);` would start `ActivityFinal` and I only want `ActivityA` to start.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what will happen. But you said you wanted to send `Bundle`s to both `Activity`s... you send a `Bundle` when you start the `Activity`. How else would it know which one to use?

Comment: Oh ok, my bad I wasen't clear. I only want to start `ActivityA` from activity `Voice`, but I want activity `Voice` to send two bundles, one bundle to `ActivtyA` and the other to `ActivityFinal`. ActivityFinal is pretty much a class that catches results or bundles, like a "results" activity..hope I explained myself better , and thnx

Comment: Yes, but until you call `startActivity` on the `putBasket_a` intent, `ActivityFinal` doesn't exist. If `ActivityFinal` has already been started from elsewhere, you can't send a `Bundle` to it.